# System.Threading.Timer или System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Я делаю окошко, в котором пользователь должен в течение ограниченного времени рисовать на InkCanvas, а потом все, что он нарисовал, должно быть стерто. Стирание будет сделано по таймеру, но я плохо понимаю, какой таймер надо выбрать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):

> "Объект System.Threading.Timer — простой таймер, использующий методы ответного вызова, который обслуживается потоками пула. Не рекомендуется использовать этот объект с Windows Forms, поскольку обратные вызовы не происходят в потоках пользовательского интерфейса. Более удобным вариантом для использования с Windows Forms является объект System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Для функций таймера, базирующихся на сервере, можно использовать System.Timers.Timer, который управляет событиями и обладает дополнительными функциями."

Соответственно, System.Timers.Timer - это то что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

System.Timers.Timer - оболочка System.Threading.Timer для использования в дизайнерах Visual Studio.
В приложениях Windows Forms лучше использовать System.Windows.Forms.Timer, т.к. данный таймер оптимизирован для приложений Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в тегах указан WPF, то ни тот, ни тот. Для UI потока в WPF есть таймер [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)